# java - can not cast to child class

Tags: java, oop, casting

I have two entity in this structure:

```
class Parent{
   public int type;
   //Setters and getters
}

class Child1 extends Parent{

}
```

I have an instance of `Parent` and I want to cast it to `Child1` based on condition in this way:

```
Parent parent = ...
if(parent.getType() == 1)
    Child1 child = (Child1) parent;
```

But it gives me `ClassCastException`. How can I resolve this problem? What's is the best way to use downcasting in java?

Comment: Check LSP principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: I assume that you are setting type to 1 in the constructor of Child1? That is a reasonably important detail if so.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `instanceof Child1` as your condition?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, you are right.

Comment: @hamed please edit your question to show that detail.

Comment: @AndyTurner If i interpret the question right, then he is creating a new instance of `Parent` and not of `Child1`, hence `instanceof Child1` won´t do any difference. I guess he magicly tries to change the class of the object based on `type` in the `Parent` class.

Comment: @hamed how do you stop me creating `class NefariousChild1 extends Parent`, which also sets `type = 1`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast a parent type object into child type object. You have misunderstod the inheritance behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

A cast to a child class is only possible if the object already *is* of that type.

A cast of an object does not change the object ot the class of an object. It just tells the compiler "this object actually is an instance of the child class, use it as such".  (Casts of primitive types are different, they actually change the type of the value!)

In your code sample you don't show how the `parent` object is created, so I don't know whether this is really the problem. Perhaps you can add the missing code to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you cast **Animal class to Dog class** ? Even though you know there are many more examples of Animals. **Its just Dog is one type of animal thats why you can cast it to Animal but Dog is not the animal**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
Parent parent = new Child1();
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't create  object properly , create object like this 
Parent child= new Child1();